# Snowflake Stored Procedure - Null in Not Null

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting error - NULL result in a non-nullable column when I execute the below stored procedure. Do you know why this is happening ?

```js
create or replace procedure Load_Employee()
  returns varchar not null
  language javascript
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  

  as
  $$
  //Variable Initialization
    
    var IntegrationTable ='EMPLOYEE';
    var TypeID=0;
    var MaxDate=' ';
    var cmd = "Select max(COMPLETED_DATE) from SCHEMA.TABLE where TARGET_TABLE_NAME=  " + "'" + IntegrationTable + "'"  ;
  
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
    var result = sql.execute();
    result.next();
 
   MaxDate=result.getColumnValue(1);
   var cmd=` Insert into PersonTable   

    select SHA1(concat(Person_id,'|','Person')) ,12345678,SHA1(concat('Payroll','|','Pay','|', Load_Date)) ,current_timestamp() , Tenant
    from Schema.PERSONTABLE

    where  TYPE='ABC' ;`;


  
  $$
  ;
```

Comment: In order to have the stored procedure return something, there should be a `return something` line somewhere within it.

Comment: I realize it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure needs to return a string somewhere, or remove the `not null` from its definition.

This stored procedure produces the same error when called:

```sql
create or replace procedure Load_Employee()
returns varchar not null
language javascript
as
$$
$$
;
  
call Load_Employee();

-- NULL result in a non-nullable column
```

This one doesn't:

```sql
create or replace procedure Load_Employee()
returns varchar not null
language javascript
as
$$
return 'hi';
$$
;
  
call Load_Employee();

-- hi
```